# Include dependency for custom sourceSet

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a `build.gradle.kts` for a small, pure kotlin project (I am aware I am using slightly non-standard source paths):

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir("src")
sourceSets["test"].java.srcDirs("test")
sourceSets {
    create("demo")?.let {
        it.java.srcDir("demo")
        // Also tried:  it.java.srcDirs("src", "demo")
        it.compileClasspath += main.get().output
        it.runtimeClasspath += main.get().output
    }
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

listOf("InteractiveClient", "LockingBufferDemo").forEach {
    tasks.register<Jar>(it) {
        manifest { attributes["Main-Class"] = "${it}Kt" }
        from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
        from(sourceSets["demo"].output) {
            include("**/${it}Kt.class")
        }
        dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
        from({
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter {
                it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
        })
    }

}
```

When I try to run one of the "demo" sourceSet based jar tasks ("InteractiveClient" and "LockingBufferDemo"),<sup>1</sup> I get a the long list of "Cannot access built-in..." errors indicating the kotlin stdlib is not properly in play.

The actual failing task is `compileDemoKotlin`, so I tried adding mimetically to the `tasks` block:

```
withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    this.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Which makes no difference.

What's strange to me is that the demo stuff was originally in the `test` sourceSet, and changing the above back to that (by removing the definition, changing `from(sourceSets["demo"]...` to `from(sourceSets.test...` in the jar task(s), and moving the source file) makes the problem disappear. It works.

I don't want this stuff in with automated tests.  I imagine I could put them in branches of the `main` or `test` set and then use a `from() { exclude(...` pattern in building the jars,
but that seems awkward and unnecessary.

**How do I get a custom source set to compile against the default project dependencies?**

---

1. See [this other recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62455921/1151724) about the `from(... include(` in the jar tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you are missing the configurations that will make the demo source sets use the same dependencies as the main set. Something like this:

```kotlin
configurations["demoImplementation"].extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
configurations["demoRuntimeOnly"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
```

There is an example in the user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) that seems to have a very similar use case as yours.

Also, from the [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13550) you created in the Gradle repository, you mentioned it failed with:

> Unresolved reference: printlin

I am pretty sure this is a typo of `println`.

Comment: That's perfect, cheers!  Kind of an odd typo because I would have cut n pasted that -- anyway I will close the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with your jar files, but I spotted a few problems in your build script:

- You have set your source sets like this:

  ```kotlin
  sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir("src")
  sourceSets["test"].java.srcDirs("src", "test")
  sourceSets {
      create("demo")?.let {
          it.java.srcDir("demo")
      }
  }
  ```

  This means you're supposed the following directory structure:

  ```
  - <module root>
    - src     <-- Belongs to both 'main' and a 'test' source sets!
    - test    <-- Belongs to the 'test' source set
    - demo    <-- Belongs to the 'demo' source set
  ```

  As you can see, there's a directory that belongs to two source sets. I'm not sure how this turns out in practice, probably one or the other is discarded. Here's a more standard directory structure:

  ```
  - <module root>
    - src
      - main
      - test
      - demo
  ```

  You configure it like this:

  ```kotlin
  sourceSets {
      main {
          java.srcDir("src/main")
      }
      test {
          java.srcDir("src/test")
      }
      create("demo") {
          java.srcDir("src/demo")
      }
  }
  ```
- The task `compileDemoKotlin` actually exists, but you can't access it just like that. If you look at the `compileKotlin` and `compileTestKotlin` extension functions source, they look like this:

  ```kotlin
  val TaskContainer.`compileKotlin`: TaskProvider<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>
      get() = named<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>("compileKotlin")
  ```

  So the trick is to use `named` to get the task instead:

  ```
  named<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>("compileDemoKotlin") {
      kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
  ```

I don't know if that answers your question. If I missed anything please let me know.

Comment: I should have indicated that I am aware I am using slightly shorter source paths than normal (so yes, those are toplevels).  *"there's a directory that belongs to two source sets.  I'm not sure how this turns out in practice..."* -> Doesn't seem to do any harm, although it wasn't necessary either (fixed).  *"use named to get the task instead"* -> I actually found a slightly different way to do this using `withType` (edited into the question) but I tried `named` too, just to be paranoid.  None of that made any difference.  Time to try the mail list and/or bug report..

Comment: *"I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with your jar files"* -> See the link in the footnote for details, but basically each one is akin to a non-automated integration test; the main project is library-esque.  So they are built from the main source set, plus a file with a main class for an executable jar.  I wanted all the demos in one directory, but only one file from that directory is compiled into each jar.